# How can I manually generate the Web Analytics Report?

Tags: web-analytics

How can I manually trigger generation of the Web Analytics Report for Traffic and Search in SharePoint 2010? It seems to run once a day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This report is generated by a timer job that can be run manually. Try these steps:

1. Go to Central Administration.
2. Click on Monitoring, then Review Job Definitions.
3. Find and click on **Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing**.
4. Click Run Now.

Please note that the reason it runs once a day is because of the additional load placed on the server. Run this job outside of normal working hours if possible.

Comment: It's for a test environment only :)